# How to generate random string using Laravel Faker between min and max number of characters

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm looking for a way to generate random string between min and max number of characters using laravel Faker.
I have to create random strings between `4` and `20` characters.
This method `str_random` will generate exactly 20 characters, but how to specify min number of characters?

```html
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => str_random(20),
    ];
});
```

Updated: I'm using the following code now as a workaround:

```
'name' => substr($faker->name(), 0, rand(4, 20))
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php might help (And `str_random()` is not a Faker method, but a Laravel one)

Comment: Yes, but I need strings, not integers.

Comment: But you need an integer between 4 and 20, right? (If `str_random(20)` generates a random string of length 20, just replace the 20 with a random integer between 4 and 20)

Comment: I was stuck with this lol. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: It's working but they are not names obviously. I couldn't find a way to do that using Faker

Comment: Also, they're not between 4 and 20 characters.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `regexify` and and this let's you control what characters could be in the randomly generated string like this:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->regexify('[A-Za-z0-9]{' . mt_rand(4, 20) . '}'),
    ];
});
```

Another option is `$faker->realText(mt_rand(4, 20))`